# Why google map is not displaying when I download my application from play store?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

- I have developed one small application related with google places.
- map is displaying and everything worked properly when I directly run the app from my PC to mobile but, when I uploaded the same app on my personal account of play store, and when I downloaded, map is not showing.
  -Is it problem related with SH1 fingerprint or related with map key?
- please help me friends as I have not found any solution though I entered proper keywords in google search.
- Thanking you in advance

my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
           android:name="com.example.maps.CurrentLocationMainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-jbt0" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you created API key with release key store??

Answer (score 0):

You Have to use ReleaeKey for google Map to release the app otherwise it will desplay blank page on Map beause you are using debug key which is running when you debug app directly from PC. 
So use Release key.

do it this way:

```
           C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin>keytool -genkey -v -keystore "C:\Users\cp
 01\.android\releasekey.ketstore" -alias release_alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048
-validity 10000
 Enter keystore password:
 Re-enter new password:
 What is your first and last name?
[Unknown]:
What is the name of your organizational unit?
[Unknown]:
What is the name of your organization?
[Unknown]:
   What is the name of your City or Locality?
[Unknown]:
What is the name of your State or Province?
[Unknown]:
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
[Unknown]:
Is CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown correct?
[no]:  yes

   Generating 2,048 bit RSA key pair and self-signed certificate (SHA1withRSA) wit
 a validity of 10,000 days
    for: CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknow

  Enter key password for <release_alias>
    (RETURN if same as keystore password):
 Re-enter new password:
 [Storing C:\Users\cpc01\.android\releasekey.ketstore]



  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin>keytool -list -alias release_alias -keyst
  re c:\Users\cpc01\.android\releasekey.ketstore
 Enter keystore password:
 release_alias, Jul 25, 2013, PrivateKeyEntry,
 Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 6A:CA:68:3D:E9:9F:B9:15:22:2A:AB:01:30:82:CC:2A

 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin>keytool -list -v -alias release_alias -ke
 store c:\Users\cpc01\.android\releasekey.ketstore
Enter keystore password:
Alias name: release_alias
Creation date: Jul 25, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
 Owner: CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown
 Issuer: CN=Unknown, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown
Serial number: 51f0c02c
 Valid from: Thu Jul 25 11:35:32 IST 2013 until: Mon Dec 10 11:35:32 IST 2040
 Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  6A:CA:68:3D:E9:9F:B9:15:22:2A:AB:01:30:82:CC:2A
     SHA1: 0F:8A:3C:6A:8F:41:CD:B4:F5:12:85:0D:B6:01:D9:30:E6:5D:28:64
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3
```

This is the compplete process of Making Release keystore and to generate SHA1 fingreprint , Now Add this SHA1 code to Register APP on Google API console.

Accept and vote answer if found useful, thanks.

Comment: is it made available from Google API console or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

*When we  upload a apk to play store we should require to signed apk and after singed apk the sha1 finger print will change and in google map v2 require a key which obtain from google console there we require SHA1 fingerprint so u should create again google map key by new SHA1 fingerprint.obtaining new SHA1 by following process

1.signed a apk.

2.again go same process you will see new sha1

3.Now create a new key and paste inside your project

4.and do signed again .

5.finally upload it

see below i upload all the pic in sequel to see new sga1 *[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]